# How to change the date in a datetime index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider a df with such an index:

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-26 15:55:00', '2018-04-26 16:00:00', '2018-04-26 16:05:00', '2018-04-26 16:10:00', '2018-04-26 16:15:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,1,1]}, index = index)

In[308]: df
Out[308]: 
                     x
date                  
2018-04-26 15:55:00  1
2018-04-26 16:00:00  1
2018-04-26 16:05:00  1
2018-04-26 16:10:00  1
2018-04-26 16:15:00  1
```

How can I set the date part of the index to an ***arbitrary*** date without using `shift` or `timedelta`, while keeping the time part of the index intact. For example, how do I change the date from 2018-04-26 to 2018-04-20 and have:

```
In[308]: df
Out[308]: 
                     x
date                  
2018-04-20 15:55:00  1
2018-04-20 16:00:00  1
2018-04-20 16:05:00  1
2018-04-20 16:10:00  1
2018-04-20 16:15:00  1
```

`df.index.date = datetime.date(2018, 4, 20)` leads to `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with index `replace` with datetime

```
df.index=df.index.map(lambda x : x.replace(day=20))
df
Out[785]: 
                     x
date                  
2018-04-20 15:55:00  1
2018-04-20 16:00:00  1
2018-04-20 16:05:00  1
2018-04-20 16:10:00  1
2018-04-20 16:15:00  1
```